# Keen.IO Hangs on read operation .net sdk

Tags: .net, keen-io

Does anyone know why Keen.IO has the similar problem of Keen.IO hanging on read operation

```
var projectsetting = new ProjectSettingsProvider("project_key",
    masterKey: "master_key",
    writeKey: "write_key",
    readKey: "read_key");
var keenClient = new KeenClient(projectsetting);
var timeframe = Keen.Core.Query.QueryRelativeTimeframe.PreviousNHours(1);

var data = keenClient.QueryExtractResource("testcategory", timeframe);// Hangs here.
```

I am only pulling approximately 1 hours worth of data and this should not take this long.

Anyone has any idea what is going on here.

Comment: Are you able to run other operations, for example a simple count?

Comment: I kind of figured the issues is with the SDK assemblies. The request does get sent out and does response however the .net SDK doesn't look like can handle this.

I used fiddler to see what happens on the net .... bit of a shame.....

Comment: @Sanj, not sure if you noticed in the answer below, but there's a Github issue for this problem at https://github.com/keenlabs/keen-sdk-net/issues/9 -- if you could help reproduce the problem, that would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

More information and investigation on this [Github issue](https://github.com/keenlabs/keen-sdk-net/issues/9#issuecomment-63510002).